# How to build a native Cocoa application with Delphi XE2 without using FireMonkey?

Tags: macos, cocoa, delphi, native

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi XE2: Is it possible to create Mac GUI applications without FireMonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442131/delphi-xe2-is-it-possible-to-create-mac-gui-applications-without-firemonkey)

Is it possible to build a native Cocoa Mac OSX application with Delphi XE2 but without using Fire Monkey?

For example in Windows I can build a native application without using VCL by utilizing the Win API only? Is similar thing possible for Mac OSX?

Any reference to how to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes is possible, check the excellent accepted answer to this question [Delphi XE2: Is it possible to create Mac GUI applications without FireMonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442131/delphi-xe2-is-it-possible-to-create-mac-gui-applications-without-firemonkey)

Comment: If it wasn't a duplicate, this would be a great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you won't have forms or a visual designer (just like when you write a Windows app using the API only).

Menu item `File->New->Other`, select `Console Application`.

Right-click `Target Platforms` in the `Project Manager`, choose `OSX 32`, check `Make target active`, then `OK`. You can delete the `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}`, if you'd like, from the project source.

Add units as you would for any API app, except from the `$(BDS)\Source\rtl\osx` folder.