# Which are the good Cocoa API ports for Delphi

Tags: cocoa, delphi, api, delphi-xe2, porting

Are there any good Cocoa API port for Delphi.

I know JCL has a good Windows API port for Delphi but it seems I miss which is the best port of Cocoa API.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XE2, take a look at the Macapi.* units. They are a pretty good port of the AppKit, the main part of Cocoa. IOW, you don't need any external ports.

Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442131/delphi-xe2-is-it-possible-to-create-mac-gui-applications-without-firemonkey/7450026#7450026) of mine.