# Create NSWindow from Delphi OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I create a NSWindow in code in Delphi for OSX?

Here is what I've tried:

```
uses Macapi.AppKit,Macapi.CocoaTypes;

...

var
  NW : NSWindow;
begin
  Nw := TNSWindow.Create;
  Nw.initWithContentRect(MakeNSRect(100,100,250,250), NSBorderlessWindowMask, NSBackingStoreBuffered, True);
```

But on the initWithContentRect line I get a runtime error in PAServer window "**_setFrameworkScaleFactor called with non-nil _borderView**".

I'm guessing I'm doing it wrong but I've found it hard to find any examples.

Comment: Did you look at FMX.Platform.Mac.pas to see how FMX does this?

Comment: @Giel Yes but it looks like they've overridden NSWindow in a TFMXWindow class. I don't see why that should be necessary and I want to do this without any FMX dependency if possible.

Comment: Are you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442131/delphi-xe2-is-it-possible-to-create-mac-gui-applications-without-firemonkey)?

Comment: @RRUZ Many thanks, that link was the key to getting it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from RRUZ (in combination with the FMX source like Giel suggested) I managed to get it working:

```
uses Macapi.AppKit, Macapi.CocoaTypes, Macapi.ObjectiveC;

...

var
  Nw : NSWindow;
begin
  Nw:= TNSWindow.Wrap(TNSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRect(
    MakeNSRect(0,100,100, 100),
    NSTitledWindowMask, NSBackingStoreBuffered, True));

  Nw.orderFront( (TNSApplication.Wrap(TNSApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID );
end;
```